# ¿Como arreglar mi constructor de array?

Tags: java, array

Estoy construyendo un constructor, al que se pasa como parámetro un array de int. Este array
se almacena en un atributo de la clase y no se modifica. Los métodos que implementan el
interface devuelven otros arrays, construidos a partir de los datos del array que no se modifica.

Esta es mi interfaz:

```
public interface Array {
    int [] subarray (int a, int b);
}
```

Y este es el constructor:

```
public class Array1 implements Array {
    
    private final int [] array;
    
    public Array1 (int [] a) {
        array = a;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public int [] subarray (int a, int b) {
        
        if (b > a || b < 0 || a >= array.length) {
            return new int [0];
        }
        
        if (a < b) {
            a = 0;
        }
        
        if (b >= array.length) {
            b = array.length - 1;
        }
        
        final int [] r = new int [b - a + 1];
        
        for (int k = 0; k < r.length; k++) {
            r[k] = array[a + k];
        }
        
        return r;
    }
```

Y por último, esta es mi clase main:

```
public class Main {
    
    private static String arrayToString (int [] a) {
    
    final StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder ("{");
  
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (k > 0) {
        r.append (",");
        }
        r.append (a[k]);
    }
  
    r.append ("}");   
  
    return r.toString ();
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
    final Array a = new Array1 (new int [] {1,5,3,6,2,4});
  
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (2,4))); // {3,6,2}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (-3,3))); // {1,5,3,6}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (3,7))); // {6,2,4}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (-5,-2))); // {}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (2,2))); // {3}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (6,6))); // {}
    }

}
```

La idea es que el método subarray devuelva un array conteniendo una parte del array inicial. Por ejemplo, si el array inicial es {1,5,3,6,2,4}, subarray(2,4) devolverá {3,6,2}, es decir, los elementos desde el 2 hasta el 4, ambos inclusive. Si el parámetro b es menor que a, o si b es menor que cero, o si a es mayor o igual que el tamaño del array, este método devolverá un array de cero elementos. Si a es negativo, se hará lo mismo que si fuese cero, y si b es mayor o igual que el tamaño del array, se hará lo mismo que si fuese uno menos que el tamaño del array. Los comentarios puestos al final de cada una de las llamadas al método son el resultado esperado que quiero al ejecutar el código.

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el código, estos son los resultados que recibo:

```
{1,5,3,6,2}
{1,5,3,6}    
{1,5,3,6,2,4}
{}
{3}
{}
```

Parece que mi código no elimina del array los primeros números del array, estoy seguro de que estoy haciendo algún cálculo mal, pero no sé exactamente dónde se encuentra el fallo, y por eso necesito ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema esta en que en el 2do. if de tu constructor, le estas diciendo que cuando b sea mayor que a (a<b), a valdrá 0, de esta forma, cuando introduces por ejemplo:

```
a.subarray (2,4);
```

El programa no entiendo un rango del 2 al 4, sino del 0 al 4, ya que b es mayor que a y por lo tanto a = 0. Por eso en los casos específicos:

```
System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (2,4)));
System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (3,7)));
```

Las salidas no son las que espera pues esta iniciando desde 0 hasta el valor de b.

Te recomiendo que elimines ese if.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, gracias a él me he dado cuenta del error, desafortunadamente la solución no era eliminar el if, sino cambiarlo de:

`if (a < b) {a = 0;}`

a:

`if (a < 0) {a = 0;}`

Para que así no diera errores con números negativos, así que gracias por tu respuesta

`código`

Comment: @ShinyaNaka si esta respuesta te fue útil deberías darle un +1 y si es la solución al problema también deberías marcarla como tal.

Comment: @ShinyaNaka me da gusto el haberte ayudado. Ten en cuenta que tú pregunta gira entorno a un comportamiento inesperado de tu código, por tal razón, mi respuesta va enfocada a señalarte dónde está el problema y de paso te sugiero una "solución". Te darás cuenta que si igual quitas el if que te indique el comportamiento inesperado se resuelve. En programación hay muchas formas de hacer las cosas, no existe una forma definitiva.